# Simplifying roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Lets say I have this: $ 2\dfrac{2}{3}\sqrt{2\dfrac{2}{3}}$ and I want to make this more simple, are my following steps correct?

$ 2\dfrac{2}{3}\sqrt{2\dfrac{2}{3}} =  2\dfrac{2}{3}\sqrt{\dfrac{24}{9}}$ = $2\dfrac{2}{3} . \dfrac{1}{3} . 2\sqrt{6} = \dfrac{16}{9} \sqrt{6}$

Comment: Looks good to me, provided that $2{2\over3}$ means two-and-two-thirds,  and not two-times-two thirds.

Comment: Thank you, it indeed means two-and-two-thirds

Answer (score 1):

$$2\frac{2}{3}\sqrt{2\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{8}{3}}=\frac{16}{3}\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}=\frac{16}{9}\sqrt{6}$$

Answer (score 0):

The second step is wrong, since $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 12$, not $24$. I think you should note that $\sqrt{2 \cdot 2} = 2$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean..

Comment: I mean, what is in the root is actually $\frac{4}{3}$, and you know that the root of a quotient is the quotient of the roots. Then, the only thing you gotta do is rationalise the result.

Comment: What busman means is that $2\cdot \frac{2}{3}$ is $\frac{12}{9}$. But as pointed out above, $2\frac{2}{3}$ in this case means $2+\frac{2}{3} = \frac{8}{3} = \frac{24}{9}$

Comment: I've never seen this notation before!

Comment: It's pretty common fraction arithmetic notation before students learn basic algebra, at least in my country.